# How to return a substring using python if a particular substring occurs in the string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to return or print a specific substring that occurs before a search keyword in a very lengthy string using python.

For example if my string is as below

```
string = "id:0, an apple a day keeps the doctor away, id=1, oranges are orange not red, id=3, fox jumps over the dog, id=4, fox ate grapes"
```

If the search keyword is apple then `0` (which is the id) should be printed

if the search keyword is orange that `1` (which are the ids) should be printed

if the search keyword is fox then `3`  and `4` (which is the id) should be printed

I'm expecting the *id* of the keyword as given in the example. In my case all the searchable keywords are associated with an *id* as in the example string.

Comment: in your original string - you have `id:0` and `id=1`. Does this mean that the number after id can be separated by either a `:` or a `=` ??

Comment: it will be separated by `:`

Comment: I edited my answer to match only a `:` or `=` separator.  If it's only a `:` then you also just use `r'id:(\d+),[\w\s]+' + word`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regex to return the indices and key word matches.

```
import re

def find_id(string, word):
    pattern = r'id[:=](\d+),[\w\s]+' + word
    return list(map(int, re.findall(pattern, string)))

string = "id:0, an apple a day keeps the doctor away, id=1, oranges are orange not red, id=3, fox jumps over the dog, id=4, fox ate grapes"

print(find_id(string, 'fox'))
```

Output:

```
[3, 4]
```

I have returned `int`s but if this isn't necessary then you can return the indices as strings `['3', '4']` by replacing the return line with;

```
return re.findall(pattern, string)
```